# CQL update query not working using Python

Tags: python, flask, cassandra, cql

I am trying to update new password after reset to cassandra db. This is the query I have written where both username and password fields are dynamic. Is this right?

```
    def update_db(uname, pwd):
        query = session.prepare('update user.userdetails set "password"=%s where "username" = ? ALLOW FILTERING', pwd)
        session.execute(query, (uname,))

update_db(username, new_pwd)
```

I am calling this through an API. But it doesn't seem to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex is absolutely correct in that you need to provide the complete `PRIMARY KEY` for any write operation.  Remove `ALLOW FILTERING` and your query should work as long as your primary key definition is: `PRIMARY KEY (username)`.

Additionally, it's best practice to parameterize your *entire* prepared statement, instead of relying on string formatting for `password`.

```
    query = session.prepare('update user.userdetails set "password"=? where "username"=?')
    session.execute(query,[pwd,uname])
```

Note: If at any point you find yourself *needing* the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

for updating record you need to provide primary key(s) completely. It will not work with `ALLOW FILTERING` - you need first to get all primary keys that you want to update, and then issue individual update commands. See the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html) for more detailed description of UPDATE command.

If you really want to specify the default value for some column - why not simply handle it with something like `.get('column', 'default-value')`?